# Promise, Defer and Variable

Tags: angularjs

I've read about promise and defer but could not really understand.
My problem is simple. I want to assign a value to a variable. But the value is coming from remote. Here is my code:

```
var page = "init";
var url = "http://url/feed";
$http(url).success(function(response) {page = response.data.page;});
$scope.main = {page:page};
```

As I understand, the $scope.main.page will get the "init" value because the 3rd line code is only a promise. Please help.

Comment: `$http(url).success(function(response) {$scope.main  = {page:response.data.page}});`

Comment: promise is asynchronous which means line 4 executes before page being assigned a value from remote.

Comment: @PSL both your anwer I can understand.. but do we have other way to make the line 4 wait for the value? means to not run asynchonously.. i do not have the words.. sorry for my broken english..

Comment: Use a resolve, which will load before your controller.

Comment: @Yang Li, Can you explain more about resolve.. I've used that, but how to get the value. deferred.promise returns empty object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "http://url/feed";

$scope.main = { page: "init" };

$http(url).success(function(response) {
  $scope.main.page = response.data.page;
});
```

If you're unclear about how async code works in javascript, I highly recommend this short talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ